Next.js: Hydration Error when Using Image Component Inside Select Element
I'm facing an issue in my Next.js application where I'm getting a hydration error when attempting to include the Image component within an  tag inside a  element. Here's the basic code structure:
<select className={styles.select}>
  <option value="kaspa">
    <Image
      src="/euno_logo.png"
      alt="kaspa logo"
      height={20}
      width={20}
    />
    Kaspa
  </option>
</select>

And the associated CSS:
.select {
  background-color: #2e374a;
  color: var(--text);
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px; /* added 'px' */
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

Despite trying various solutions, I'm consistently encountering the following error:
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
Image is missing required "alt" property. Please add Alternative Text to describe the image for screen readers and search engines.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <img> cannot appear as a child of <option>.

I've attempted conditional rendering and positioning the Image component using CSS, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this hydration error and successfully incorporate the Image component within the  element without causing this problem?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
